# Which of these graphs are homotopic but not homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, classifying-spaces

I am struggling with the 'homotopic' part of the question

> Which of these are homotopic but not homeomorphic?

[image: Graphs]

The number of vertices of degree $\neq 2$ is a topological invariant, thus is true for homeomorphic space.

Respective to the above picture the number of vertices of degree $1$ are: $2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 0      $ and $1  $

Respective to the above picture the number of vertices of degree $3$ are: $  2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0    $ and $1 $

This distinguishes all cases except for $\mathbb{\phi}$ and $\mathbb{6}$ which both have a degree $1$ vertex of degree $1$ and a degree $3$ vertex of degree $1$

These are the only ones that can be homeomorphic, but they are not since $\phi$ has a vertex of degree $4$ and $6$ does not.

So all graphs are not homeomorphic.

So I have done the homeomorphic part, but I am struggling on the homotopic part. Could you help me with that?

Comment: From left to right, can you see how to deform the second figure into the rectangle? Are they homeomorphic?

Comment: The basic thing to do is retract edges that are sticking out. So for instance the upside-down A is homotopic to the triangle at the bottom.

Comment: so we just consider the bits that are 'closed off' in a sense?